# Difference between "I let my hair grow." and "I grow my hair."

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference in meaning between "I grow my hair out." and "I let my hair grow out." Another example is between "I dry my hair naturally." and "I let my hair dry naturally." I can see both sentences, but am not sure about the differences.  Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say:

> I grow my hair out.
>   I dry my hair naturally.

you are just saying what you do.

If you say:

> I let my hair grow out.
>   I let my hair dry naturally.

it means you purposely do this; you could choose not to but don't.
It is similar to: *I **choose to** let my hair dry naturally.*